# Collection of open intervals covering rationals in (0,1) where sum of lengths is less than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$A$ is the set of rationals in the interval $(0,1)$.  I'd like to find a collection of open intervals $\{I_{n}\}$ covering $A$ where $\sum l(I_{n})<1$.

This collection, I believe, must be infinite.

As I understand it the set of rationals themselves in this interval would be neither closed nor open in the reals: every interval around a rational would contain an irrational, and every interval around an irrational would contain a rational.

I am working on a problem where finiteness of the collection of $\{I_{n}\}$ is a requirement for $\sum I_{n}\geq 1$.  (I think I have a proof of this that works just fine).

But I don't understand completely why finiteness is required.

Comment: First, enumerate the rationals in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 3):

You can do even better, since $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$ has measure $0$, so $\forall \epsilon>0$, we can find intervals $I_n$ such that $A\subset \bigcup I_n$ and $\sum l(I_n)\leq\epsilon$ so that $m(A)\leq \epsilon$. The idea is that $A$ is countable, so $A=\{q_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Now let $$I_n=\left(q_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},q_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}\right)$$ It is easy to see that $\sum l(I_n)\leq\epsilon\sum 1/2^{n}=\epsilon$

Comment: it was excellent.

Comment: Not what was asked, though.

Comment: @JessyCat How so? The question asked for a countable collection of open intervals covering $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$ with measure less than $1$. This proof shows that by taking $\epsilon<1$. The problem of finiteness was secondary.

Comment: Wait, why is $\epsilon \sum 1/2^n = \epsilon$?